# Compatibility of the Hausdorff measure with short exact sequences in normed spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(E,\|.\|)$ be a finite dimensional normed space and take $F\subset E$ a 
subpace, so that we have the canonical short exact sequence 
$0\rightarrow F\rightarrow^\iota E\rightarrow^\pi E/F\rightarrow 0$ of normed spaces ($F$ 
being endowed by the restriction of $\|.\|$ and $E/F$ by the quotient norm
$\|v+F\| = \inf_{f\in F} \|v-f\|$). Write $n=\dim E$ and $k = \dim F$.

We can define the Hausdorff measure on each of these spaces (say $\mu_F, \mu_E$ and $\mu_{E/F}$), deriving from 
each of their norms. 
Is this definition compatible with the short exact sequence, 
in the sense that for a $k$-vector $\mathfrak{f} = f_1\wedge \cdots\wedge f_k\in\bigwedge^k E$, and $\mathfrak{e} = e_{k+1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n\in \bigwedge^{n-k} E$, we have:
$$
\mu_E(\mathfrak{f} \wedge \mathfrak{e}) = \mu_F(\mathfrak{f})\mu_{E/F}(\pi(\mathfrak{e}\wedge\mathfrak{f})).
$$

Remark that this is the case when $\|.\|$ is Euclidean, as a direct consequence of the definition of the norm on the exterior algebra.

Another way of looking at the question is whether the *comeasure* induced by the Hausdorff measure coincidates with the measure induced by the quotient norm.

Comment: No it is not. You can find counterexamples in dimension two already. I think the max norm on the plane and almost any $1$-dimensional subspace will be a counterexample. I'll come back later when I have more time.

Comment: And what about with a proper renormalization of the measure, let say by a factor A_k depending only the rank k ?

Comment: No that won't work either. Volumes in normed spaces are tricky things. See my paper with Thompson on A Sampler of Riemann Finsler Geometry: http://library.msri.org/books/Book50/contents.html